# How to add Copyright Notice Code?

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, journals, conference

I have got a paper accepted in a conference, they have told me add a copyright notice code at the bottom of page 1. This is my first time in conference and I am confused whether the code is same for every paper based on the government/country or unique for every paper.

Eg.
For papers in which all authors are employed by the US government, the copyright notice is:

U.S. Government work not protected by U.S. copyright

For papers in which all authors are employed by a Crown government (UK, Canada, and Australia), the copyright notice is:
979-X-XXXX-XXXX-X/23/$31.00 ©2023 Crown

For papers in which all authors are employed by the European Union, the copyright notice is: 979-X-XXXX-XXXX-X/23/$31.00©2023 European Union

For all other papers the copyright notice is (Majority of papers will fall in this category):
979-X-XXXX-XXXX-X/23/$31.00 ©2023 IEEE
As shown below on 1st page of paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same notice for all papers in this conference that do not fall under crown / government notice.